# Mojofailureexception with Vaadin 20 and Webpack.js

Tags: spring, typescript, webpack, frontend-maven-plugin

I've been trying to create a new app with vaadin-fusion (version 20), being an inexperienced student developer, I cannot resolve or even pinpoint the origin of the error that arises every time I attempt to compile frontend with vaadin designer (basically) every time the app is about to launch in Maven, this evidently, not a Maven-specific error, I attach the following stacktrace:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal [com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:20.0.7:build-frontend(default-cli)on project myapp 
Could not execute build-frontend goal
Error occured during goal execution: There can only be one @PWA annotation and it must be set on the AppShellConfigurator implementor.Please run Maven with the -e switch (or Gradle with the --stacktrace switch), to learn the full stack trace. 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -eswitch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR]  http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

The wiki link explains that maven error is caused by something else. The `@PWA` I haven't used at all. Perhaps, its a problem at the level of webcomponents module, which means its Vaadin's fault. Please, help has anyone encountered a similar problem? If yes, how did you resolve it?

Comment: Couple of points to check for you. 20.0.7 is not the latest version. I would recommend to try with 21.0.3, 20.x is not supported anymore. Also, you can download functional Fusion starter app from start.vaadin.com and start modifying it.

Comment: I strated out by downoading a functional app from start.vaadin.com, it doesn not affect the issue I am raising

Comment: It's hard to know what's going on without the source code that reproduces the problem you are having. Is it possible to put a sample code that creates the problem in your question? If it turns out to be too much of a problem, you can talk to us directly in Discord - https://vaad.in/fusion

Comment: Oh, reading the question again I realized something: apparently you are trying to open a Vaadin Fusion application in Vaadin Designer - that doesn't work. Vaadin Designer only works with Vaadin Flow.

Comment: The error message suggests that during the build, there were multiple classes with a `@PWA` annotation found during the build. The application downloaded from start.vaadin.com should have only one such a class. Could you, please, try searching for the `@PWA` in the source and double-check that there are no duplicates?